# Hasten website information pulling

Tags: android, xml, json, web-applications, information-retrieval

Hi currently my android webapp involves pulling XML data from website and converting them into JSON format before accessing the data. 
However, due to the large amount of data, my application initialization is slow, ~ 12seconds.

Does anyone know what are the methods possible to hasten the process? Those information i work on are live info.

Thanks.

Comment: Please elaborate on your current implementation.

Comment: Why not just parse the XML?

Comment: my current implementation is as follow :
var JSON_CarparkRates = JSON.stringify($.xml2json(info.CarparkRates()));

info.carparkRates is a javascript interface class,
and converting it to json and stringify it at my javascript class in my web app. I get the xml data in java and passed it over to my javascript class.